# Captcha image cannot be refresh by using Glide

Tags: android, imageview, okhttp, android-glide

I have tried to use Glide to load an Captcha image into a ImageView. The first time loading is fine. However, when I reload the Captcha image into the same ImageView, the ImageView does not refresh to new image. Does anyone have idea how to solve this issue?

```
String url = "https://captcha_path";
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgView);

Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always use [Glide.clear()](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clear(com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target)) and then call Glide.with(...).load() again. If your url doesn't change when the image changes, you may also need to add [.skipMemoryCache(true)](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#skipMemoryCache(boolean)) to your load call. For more control, check out the [.signature()](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#signature(com.bumptech.glide.load.Key)) API. You can always do something like:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
    .into(imgView);
```

Comment: I try use Glide.clear(imageView). ImageView ( method imageView.getTag()) include tag TAG = com.bumptech.glide.request.GenericRequest@425455e0, but Glide don't clear view and don't update image (url the same). Add signature - work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Monkeyless, you are right. I have used .skipMemoryCache(true) and it worked fine. However, I am facing another issue. When I load the captcha image, sometimes it can show on ImageView. Sometimes it cannot but without any exception. Any idea?

Comment: Check out the debugging page on the project wiki and consider creating an issue if you can reproduce this reliably: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Debugging-and-Error-Handling

Comment: .signature worked fine,but what's the impact of using it ? and what does it actually do ?

Comment: Signature changes the in memory and disk cache key. So using a new random signature each time effectively disables both the disk cache and the memory cache. You could use DiskCacheStrategy.NONE, but that's not sufficient because the memory cache key may still match. skipMemoryCache will only skip checking the memory cache, not checking active resources, so it's not sufficient either, even when paired with DiskCacheStrategy.NONE.

Comment: Creating this signature each time makes it go slow. There must be a better way

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
    .into(imgView);
```

Replace `StringSignature` with `ObjectKey` (for Glide v4)

```
Glide.with(fragment)
        .load(url)
        .signature(new ObjectKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
        .into(imgView);
```

Comment: Creating this signature each time makes it load slower. There must be a better way