# Force downloading image when online

Tags: android, android-glide

When I'm using glide to load images they are loaded first from memory not from server. So I'm checking If phone has internet connection I'm adding to glidebuilder  `skipMemoryCache(true)` but image is still not downloaded, and loaded from memory. Any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26856780/1841194

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto but when I will set signature it will not be loaded when I'm will be offline? Maybe when I will save signature and load image with signature which was saved when phone was online it will work, but this will be shity solution IMO

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this library. IMO, [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) could be better. not?