# Glide not updating image android of same url?

Tags: java, android, caching, imageview, android-glide

I have **the same url** for an image. When I update this image more than one time it shows the previous image. The image and picture version  on the server is updated but Glide is not showing the new image.I want to get new image every time and cache it .

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(Constants.COPY_LINK_BASE_URL + info.getDisplayPicture())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile).dontAnimate()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .signature(new (SettingManager.getUserPictureVersion(context)))
        .into(ivUserProfilePhoto);
```

I can reproduce this bug by changing internet ,on one internet its change image as expected on other internet it remain same after 2 or 3 tries to changing image

Comment: your cached image is being displayed. Make your own disk cache mechanism and flush out the old image when there is a new one available on server. Check this https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#size might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captcha image cannot be refresh by using Glide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836489/captcha-image-cannot-be-refresh-by-using-glide)

Comment: in his question he is not using signature api , i am already using it

Answer (score 31):

```
//Use bellow code, it work for me.Set skip Memory Cache to true. it will load the image every time.

 Glide.with(Activity.this)
.load(theImagePath)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.into(myImageViewPhoto);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,but this does not full fill my requirnment

Comment: You need to change url from server everytime, if you want to load image everytime. another wise Glide load same image which is first one, if URL not get changed.

Comment: Problem is url can not be changed

Comment: The problem is that your photo will be loaded every time and this can consume time, in some cases where the image is too large, it can even lead to timeout. Maybe it is a good idea to save a boolean in sharedPreferences to say when the uri should be reloaded.

Comment: Turning the cache off is a really bad solution.

Comment: Doing this won't update Glide's cache, even if it fetched a newer image (AFAIK). So subsequent calls with cache enabled won't return the image you previously got with `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE`.

Comment: Wow! I spent a lot of time for solving that problem... Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

**Glide 4.x**

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
     .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
     .into(imageView);
```

**Glide 3.x**

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 23):

### TL;DR.

1. you can skip caching by adding the following lines:

   **GLIDE v4**

   ```
   Glide.with(context)
           .load(url)
           .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
           .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
           .into(imageView);
   ```

   **GLIDE v3**

   ```
   Glide.with(context)
           .load(url)
           .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
           .skipMemoryCache(true)
           .into(imageView);
   ```
2. **OR** : you can workaround caching by adding a dummy random argument to your `URL`:

   ```
   Glide.with(context)
           .load(url + "?rand=" + (new Random().nextInt()))
           .into(imageView);
   ```

### What's happening?

When your picture is loaded the first time, it's stored locally in what's called a cached memory (or simply "a cache"). When you request it for a second time Glide fetches if from the cache as if it was a successful request. This is meant for many good reasons such as: offloading your server, saving your users some data, and responding quickly (offering your users a smooth experience).

### What to do?

You will need to disable the cache to force Glide to fetch your image remotely every time you ask for it. You can do the following:

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(url)
         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
         .skipMemoryCache(true)
         .signature(imageVersion) // supposing that each new image has its own version number
         .into(imageView);
```

Or, in the case where you can't know when a picture is changing (no `imageVersion`), use a unique signature for each picture.

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(url)
         .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
         .into(imageView);
```

Another clean way would be to configure your picture's cache strategy in your server and use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)`.

#### A hacky trick worth mentioning

If adding a dummy query aramter to your target URL doesn't break anything, then you could simply workaround caching by passing a random argument each time you fetch the image. This will force *Glide* to pull your image from your sever since no image with that random url can possibly exist in your cache.

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(url + "?rand=" + (new Random().nextInt())) // "&rand=" if your url already has some GET params
         .into(imageView);
```

---

Glide caching API [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation).

Comment: Due to requirement i can not load picture every time

Comment: If u want to keep the cache, u can add some extra code into your server to see if the image has changed or not. If it did change then u'll clear it for the cache and load the updated one, if not just fetch it from the cache.

Comment: signature comes from server that tell image on url is changed

Comment: This solution worked for me. The only change I have to do is to use different object for signature "ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())" instead the suggested. This helps if you are using Glide Version 4 and above.

Answer (score 9):

I my case Glide not recognize `.signature()`, so additionally to @MGDavies's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194793/6733404) you maybe need something like this

```
// in kotlin
Glide.with(context)
        .load("url")
        //using apply to RequestOptions instead signature directly
        .apply(RequestOptions().signature(ObjectKey("time that image was updated")))
        .into(thumb)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, so I'm sure you've got your fix by now. However I believe both of the big libraries(Picasso and Glide) now support something similar.

Glide has its signature API you may wish to look into:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
    .load(yourFileDataModel)
    .signature(new StringSignature(yourVersionMetadata))
    .into(yourImageView);
```

I've not had a chance to work with this myself, but it looks as though you need to make a call to your API to get the version Metadata, then a subsequent call to fulfil it.

Alternatively, look into ETags.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**Glide 4.8.0**

```
Glide.with(mContext).asBitmap()
                    .load(nopicUrl)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.signatureOf(new ObjectKey(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))))
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA))
                    .into(ivImageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Now **Glide latest** version, you have to use `RequestOption` for clear cache.

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true);
```

Or for everytime load picture you have to use a **String** in as `signature`.

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
.signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

Finally:

```
Glide.with(CompressSingleActivity.this)
.applyDefaultRequestOptions(options)
.load(currentFile)
.into(currentImageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

**When new images are loaded or updated, use below to clear Glide memory and cache** :

|==| Clear Glide memory

```
 Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearMemory();
```

|==| Clear Glide Cache()

```
void clearGlideDiskCache()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearDiskCache();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: This seems super wasteful in order to only clear whole cache a single image. Good to know, but not a recommended solution for this specific question

Answer (score 1):

`diskCacheStrategy` and `skipMemoryCache` did not work for my case.

I was writing to a local image file between Glide requests with the same url. My hack of a solution was to switch between adding a 0/1 to the end of the filename.

Forcing it to change image source every time seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RequestOptions:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```

If .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions) does not work, use .apply(requestOptions):

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(imageview);
 // or this
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.booked_circle).error(R.drawable.booked_circle))
            .into(imageview);

 // or this
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.booked_circle).error(R.drawable.))
            .into(imageview);
```

Answer (score -1):

it's like the issue is related to Glide Library itself, I found the trick that can fix this, just put a random number after your image URL as a query like an Example code below, it fixed my problem I hope it helps you too

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomInt = random.nextInt();
        Glide.with(context)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
                        .circleCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                .load(ConstantVars.BaseUrl + userModel.getAvatarURL() + "?" + randomInt)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.himart_place_holder))
                .into(imageViewProfile);
```

it will make Glide to reload image anytime you request like there's no cache at all to read from.