# How to load image from same url using glide or picasso in android?

Tags: android

Hi I have an wired issues stopping my development. I am working on the application similar to facebook having posts, comments likes and chat functionalities. In each functionality I need to load the user's profile picture. I can able to load the profile pictures when I was trying to login for the first time using **glide** libary. But **when users changes the profile picture server is returning the same url but different image**. How to invalidate or load image when it was updated and what are the best ways to handle this scenario?

Your answers are valuable to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in glide use DiskCacheStartergy

Comment: can you please elaborate in broad?

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("URL")
                .asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.man_default)
                .into(imgUserImage);
```

Comment: what this code asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) do?

Comment: I tried with above answer. Returning the same image because of glide having cache behaviour.

Comment: asBitmap() is optional but DiskCacheStrategy use different parameters. try with DiskCacheStrategy.NONE

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but when we are doing ".diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)" to image view, every time it loads from the server right? In that case, performance of the app will decreases.

Comment: then uses Picasso. it is better than glide

Answer (score 1):

For Picasso you can use both `MemoryPolicy` and `NetworkPolicy`

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(imageViewFromNetwork);
```

refer [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching) its well explained here!

Answer (score 0):

I think disabling cache strategy will be helpful for you as your url is same so

```
DiskCacheStrategy.NONE
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)

difference between the enum parameters for the `.diskCacheStrategy()` method:

**DiskCacheStrategy.NONE** caches nothing, as discussed

**DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE** caches only the original full-resolution image. In our example above that would be the 1000x1000 pixel one

**DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT** caches only the final image, after reducing the resolution (and possibly transformations) (default behavior)

**DiskCacheStrategy.ALL** caches all versions of the image

try using:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile)
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .into(ivUserProfilePhoto);
```

here is a relevant [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758087/glide-not-updating-image-android-of-same-url)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but when we are doing ".diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .skipMemoryCache(true) " to image view, every time it loads from the server right? In that case, performance of the app will decreases.

Comment: depends...it will affect only the profile picture image loading...not the other. also you can check condition is the image updated then apply `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` otherwise use the caching

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to give you suggestion over it.

First, you should remember every profile has unique URL and it should be immutable on the server.

These issue is more sort of on server side because you never know on client side when other users changed their profile pictures but server knows.

Probable solution we have done for it

1. Whenever any user changes in profile picture we saving these picture on server with his timestamp and it attached to it's URL.
   eg : http://image.pngtimestamp=1336t78387
2. So, now you have different URL for the user profile you don't have to change it on client side.
3. Only thing you have to take care for it is how you will get these updated URL for the specific user.We are requesting for URL to server whenever we chat with other user or see his profile. so every time we get the latest pic.

Even you want to improve performance for it you can request for updated images URL at the start of your application when user launch app so server can return you all the images after given timestamp.

Hope these helps you.